# Angular - Load the app from a shareable URL

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, angular9, angular-router

Folks,

I have an Angular 9 app which have a set of views implemented for specific features. It has got a nested structure for the views like,

**A(list page) -> B (list page when clicked an item in A's list) -> C(details page while clicking an item from B's list)**

C has multiple sub-views each of which has an route associated with it.

My requirement here is to share the url of the app (say when the user is in C's sub-view) to someone and if that user is already logged in, he/she should be taken to exact page.

Currently we are not storing any of the identifiers(id) in the url, instead we are keeping it in sessionstorage. So when the user refreshes the url, we can restore the app state without any issues.

A couple of questions here:

1. Is it fine to keep the identifiers of each route in the browser url like (a/2/b/3) or any security implications with this approach ?
2. How do we normally handles the identifiers if we have a deeply nested structure like (a/1/b/2/c/3/d/4...) ?
3. Is it possible to load an app with url, if we are not storing the identifiers as part of the url?
4. How basically we implement this kind of shareable url in Angular app?

Any help/thoughts on this is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You never want to put any sensitive information in a route like an account number. Any information you can pass by the route needs to be verified by your api to stop people access information they should not have access to. You can nest routes as deep as you want, each route can lazy load other routing modules. Read up on the Angular router, it is very well documented at angular.io

https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Thanks @Adrian Brand. Actually my question is more focused towards creating a bookmarkable url for an Angular 9 app with nested routes.